# QNetworkProxy - Bypass Certain Addresses

Tags: c++, windows, qt, proxy, qt5

In my QT5 application (Windows environment), I'm setting application-wide proxy using:

```
        QNetworkProxy proxy;
        proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy::HttpProxy);
        proxy.setHostName(proxyHost);
        proxy.setPort(proxyPortInt);
```

My client has an exception list for their proxy. However when I set my proxy as above, that exception list is not being used as expected.

In Internet Options you can specify an exception list as:
[image: Proxy Exception List]

So my questions are:

1. Is it possible for me to get that exception list?
2. Can I somehow register this exception list to QNetworkProxy?

EDIT:
I've noticed that I can get that exception list from registry:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ ProxyOverride
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. QNetworkProxy has no exception list. If you use an application wide proxy the best thing you can do is to disable the proxy for certain sockets by calling `serverSocket->setProxy(QNetworkProxy::NoProxy)`, but you can't disable it for certain hostnames. You will have to check before the connection is estabilished if a proxy should be used and then either disable or set it.

Comment: any help about how to achieve this for QNetworkAccessManager or QWebEngineView?

Comment: @ OzanYukruk Have a look at the Qt source. https://github.com/radekp/qt/blob/master/src/network/access/qnetworkaccessmanager.cpp#L571 - It calls createRequest before connecting which is available as virtual function in QNAM `QNetworkReply *QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest`, Eventually you can re-implement it and read the destination and then disable it if it matches one of your non-proxy hostnames. I have not tried this. There are no interesting slots that are called before the connection is created, so I don't see any other possiblity.

Comment: I see, after reading your comment, I've just checked If i can override QWebEngineView proxy, but it seems I can not.

So If I understood correctly, QWebEngineView only takes application-wide proxy. There Is no such thing like QWebEngineView::setProxy.

Comment: Yeah, looks like https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtwebengine-overview.html#proxy-support - but you can modify the Qt source-code, it shouldn't be too hard to add such an exception feature.